# Как избавится от необходимости вызывать join() у потока при использовании ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня многопоточный код с всего одним методом, но не как не получается, добиться его стабильной работы.

Я попытался использовать `ConcurrentHashMap`, но безуспешно. Почему не понимаю.

```
public class UserStorage implements Storage {
    // По идее все вопросы по синхронизации ConcurrentHashMap должна снимать.
    private Map<Integer, Account> accounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean addAccount(final Account account) {
        final Account a = this.accounts.get(account.getId());
        if (a != null) {
            return false;
        }

        this.accounts.put(account.getId(), account);
        return true;
    }
}


public class Consumer {
    private Storage storage = new UserStorage();

    public boolean addAccount(BigDecimal amount, String name, Integer id) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadAdd thread = new ThreadAdd(amount, name, id);
        thread.start();
        //thread.join(); // вот этот join мне все портит без него не работает, а с ним однопоточный код получается.
        return thread.added;
    }

    // класс потока
    private class ThreadAdd extends Thread {
        private boolean added;

        private BigDecimal amount;
        private String name;
        private Integer id;

        private ThreadAdd(BigDecimal amount, String name, Integer id) {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.add();
        }

        private void add() {
            Account account = new User(this.amount, this.name, this.id);
            this.added = Consumer.this.storage.addAccount(account);
        }
    }
}
```

А запускаю все это хозяйство так:

```
@Test
public void whenAddWithOriginalIdThenAddAccountReturnTrue() throws InterruptedException {
    List<Boolean> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        result.add(consumer.addAccount(new BigDecimal("32"), "name", i));
    }

    result.forEach(Assert::assertTrue);
}
```

Я уже и `Hashtable` пробовал, и в синхронизированый блок тело `UserStorage.addAccount(...)` упаковывал, (и с отдельным монитором и с `this`), и просто метод как `synchronized` помечал. Все равно валится. Только когда метод `join()` в `Consumer.addAccount` использую, тогда работает. Но это всю многопоточность убивает... Помогите пожалуйста как это решить? Надо сделать чтобы пользователи в мапу добавлялись в несколько потоков.

Comment: Валится - это что значит?

Comment: @etki то значит что я добавляю Account ты с оригинальными id а у меня в тесте в result false попадают. По идее в result все значения должны быть true потому что единственное условие успешного добавления аккаунта это оригинальный id, а он у меня определяется инкрементов в цикле теста: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        result.add(consumer.addAccount(new BigDecimal("32"), "name", i));
    }

Comment: У вас ничего не сдерживает forEach от выполнения до того, как все задачи выполнились. Вам так или иначе необходимо сделать синхронизацию задач, проще всего с ExecutorService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно к полю added добавить модификатор volatile так как поле используется в нескольких потоках.
2. Нужно как-то ждать пока пользователь добавится потому что поток может успеть отработать до момента возврата из consumer.addAccount, а может и не успеть. Для этого правильнее было бы потокам дать место куда складировать результат добавления и после окончания работы всеми потоками уже смотреть результаты.